OneSignal Push notification works in iPhone 14 but not iPhone SE and iPhone 11
I implemented push notification using OneSignal. I am using Objective-C.
Here is the part of Pod file.
target 'PlugYou' do
  ...
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.11.2', '< 3.0'
end
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.11.2', '< 3.0'
end

It works well in iPhone 14 but not iPhone SE and iPhone 11, which iOS version is 17.6.1
Please help me.
I need to make push notification works in all the iOS devices.
Thanks.
